# Неправильное отображение вертикального wxToolBar

Tags: c++, gui, wxwidgets

В моем приложении должен быть вертикальный toolbar с текстом слева. Создаю так:

```
wxToolBar *tools=new wxToolBar(this,wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,
    wxTB_VERTICAL|wxTB_FLAT|wxTB_TEXT|wxTB_HORZ_TEXT|wxTB_HORZ_LAYOUT);
```

Потом в него добавляю RadioButtonЫ функцией AddRadioButton.
На Linux результат нормальный: кнопки выровнены по центру, одной ширины и в один столбец.

[image: test-linux]

А на Windows вот такая проблема: кнопки не только разной ширины, так еще и в несколько рядов.

[image: test-windows]

Есть ли решение этой проблемы? Придется ли наследоваться от wxToolBar для этого?

Comment: тебя насильно заставляют учить wxwidgets?

Comment: Нет, просто уже много кода написано с помощью него.